# Conditionally independent random variable

Tags: probability

My doubt is the following: If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables conditionally independent given random variable $H$, why can I write the following three equalities?

$f_{X,Y} (x,y) = \int f_{X,Y,H} (x,y,u)du = \int f_{X,Y|H=u} (x,y) f_H (u)du$

where $f_{X,Y}$ is the joint p.d.f of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I don't understand why it do not appear the integrals and the subscripts correctly, if anyone can help me, I appreciate that.

Comment: I am trying to do that

Comment: Maybe try writing out these for the discrete case and it may be more clear in that case to help develop intuition.

Answer (score 0):

By definition you have:
$$f_{X,Y|H=h}(x,y|h) = \frac{f_{X,Y,H}(x,y,h)}{f_H(h)}
$$
Hence:
$$f_{X,Y,H}(x,y,h) = f_{X,Y|H=h}(x,y|h)\cdot f_H(h)
$$
If you integrate this over the domain of $h$ you get your second equality.

The first equality is purely the definition of a *marginal distribution*.

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Now, I understand, thank you so much Andrei.

Comment: However, I still do not understand the first equality of my question.

Comment: Please check the definition of a marginal distribution. You simply have that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \int f_{X,Y,H}(x,y,h) dh$. Basically what this says in plain English is that if you are interested in the distribution of only a certain number of the random variables that you have, you need to integrate (sum) over the whole space of the rest.